# Why is Vite/TS bundling both production and development versions of react-jsx-runtime?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite, rollup

I am using `"jsx": "react-jsx",` in my tsconfig file and using Vite/rollup for bundling. For some reason my module is always bundling with both `react-jsx-runtime.production.min.js` and `react-jsx-runtime.development.js`, even when NODE_ENV is set to production. I only expect the production code to be included.

I can remove both by setting `'react/jsx-runtime'` to external in rollup options, but this is also not what I want for the prod bundle. I can't find docs that explain this. Does anyone know how I can stop the bundler from including the development runtime?

**vite.config.ts**

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    lib: {
      entry: './src/index.tsx',
      formats: ['es'],
      name: `button`,
      fileName: `button`,
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      external:  ['react'],
    },
  },
  plugins: [react()],
})
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["DOM", "DOM.Iterable", "ESNext"],
    "allowJs": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}
```

**tsconfig.node.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "include": ["vite.config.ts"]
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "button",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production vite build && npx tsc"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-is": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.26",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.9",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^3.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.9.3",
    "vite": "^4.0.0"
  }
}
```

**src/index.tsx**

```
import React, { FC } from 'react'

export const Button: FC<any> = ({
  children
}) => (
  <button>{children}</button>
)

export default Button
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will strip out the development runtime, but it's all academic as this is probably not the correct way to bundle a library.

```
export default defineConfig((env) => ({
  define: env.command === 'build' ? { "process.env.NODE_ENV":  "'production'" } : undefined,
...
```

On reflection, it makes more sense to add `react/jsx-runtime` to the external rollup options, or use the opt out as suggested by @Danielo Velasquez

Comment: This is the correct answer. I am unsure why Vite is not honoring the 'NODE_ENV=production' environment variable. Nevertheless, it seems to be the sole method to make Vite recognize the environment variable.

I verified this works using https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-bundle-visualizer

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem but I found a tutorial on medium where it explained the creation of libraries with vite, I show you my config that avoids external dependencies

```
build: {
  ...
  rollupOptions: {
    external: [
      'react',
      "react/jsx-runtime",
      'react-dom',
    ],
    output: {
      globals: {
        'react': 'react',
        'react-dom': 'ReactDOM',
        'react/jsx-runtime': 'react/jsx-runtime',
      },
    },
  },
},
```

hug from argentina

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer! It has been doing my head in all day. For some reason, this only seems to happen when upgrading to 3.x of Vite. 2.9.16 would only bundle runtime.production so I started noticing the difference. This looks to remove both which is great!

Answer (score 2):

I stumble to the same issue and I solved by opting out of the automatic JSX runtime.

```js
react({
  jsxRuntime: 'classic',
})
```

This will disable the automatic JSX runtime and the size of your output will decrease.

Source: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vitejs/plugin-react

Comment: Sounds like maybe it's a bug then?

Comment: Thanks, I tried this option, but it stops the bundling of the runtime entirely. I do want (only) the production runtime. The issue for me is that both the development and production versions of the runtime are bundled together. I only want one or the other, in this case the production one.

Answer (score 0):

Define `react/jsx-runtime` in your [build.rollupOptions.external](https://rollupjs.org/configuration-options/#external) configuration -

```js
build: {
  lib: {
    ...
  },
  rollupOptions: {
    external: [
      "react",
      "react/jsx-runtime",
      "react-dom",
    ],
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> In library mode, all import.meta.env.* usage are statically replaced when building for production. However, process.env.* usage are not, so that consumers of your library can dynamically change it. If this is undesirable, you can use define: { 'process.env.NODE_ENV': '"production"' } for example to statically replace them, or use esm-env for better compatibility with bundlers and runtimes.

https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#library-mode